# PHP - Adding code to a output string

Tags: php

I have a bit of an easy question which i cant seem to figure out.

I have the following line

```
$output .= '    <input name="_'.$row->key.'" style="height: 10px; margin: 0;" type="checkbox" id="'.$row->key.'" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size: 9px; text-transform: lowercase;">'.$row->name.'</span>';
```

and i need to add the following to it, but they are different format

```
trim(set_radio("allwork", "1")) == 'checked="checked"' ? true : false
```

If i do '. and .' before and after the trim section and insert it, it throws errors

Cheers,

Comment: Consider putting your CSS in a stylesheet instead of inline.

Comment: The ` ? true : false` part is redundant. But as for your problem, you might want to put such constructs into utility functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris: Try --

```
$output .= '    <input name="_'.$row->key.'" style="height: 10px; margin: 0;" type="checkbox" id="'.$row->key.'"';
if (trim(set_radio("allwork", "1")) == 'checked="checked"') { $output .= ' checked="checked"'; }
$output .= ' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size: 9px; text-transform: lowercase;">'.$row->name.'</span>';
```

Answer (score 2):

For in-line conditions you should wrap them in parenthesis then you can concatenate them. For example:

```
echo "Hello, " . ($a == $b ? "world." : "universe.");
```

**EDIT** corrected syntax, my apologies to those taking "b" literally.

Comment: This will throw an error because b is not a proper php variable.  Unless it' a predefined constants which should be capitalized per php documentary.